# derived class as a parameter of templated function which is specialized for its base class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, derived-class

```
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

class SomeClass
{
    template<typename T>
    static void SetContent(T* pChild, OVariant content)
    {
        LOG_ASSERT(0, "All classes must be specialized!.  Please provide implementation for this class.");
    }
};

template <>
void SomeClass::SetContent(Base* value) 
{
    LOG_TRACE("Yay!");
}

int main() {
    SomeClass foo;
    Derived derived;
    foo.SetContent(&derived);//want it to call SomeClass::SetContent(Base* value) 
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I call foo.SetContent(derived), I get the Assert.  Is it not possible for the derived class to use the specialization for it's base class?

Comment: Template instantiation doesn't "combine" with implicit conversions.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is exactly, but based on your code I made some example code that might help you find a solution or come up with a better question.
https://godbolt.org/z/PcP9aeorr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a `Derived*` to a `Base*`, but I think you rather want to specialize for all `T` that have `Base` as base

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};


template <typename T,typename = void>
struct impl {
    void operator()(T*) {
        std::cout <<"All classes must be specialized!.  Please provide implementation for this class.\n";
    }
};
template <typename T>
struct impl<T,std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base,T>>> {
    void operator()(T*) {
        std::cout << "Yay\n";
    }
};

class SomeClass
{
    public:
    template<typename T>
    static void SetContent(T* pChild)
    {
        impl<T>{}(pChild);    
    }
};

struct bar{};

int main() {
    SomeClass foo;
    Derived derived;
    foo.SetContent(&derived);
    bar b;
    foo.SetContent(&b);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/K5Y8cbYh4):

```
Yay
All classes must be specialized!.  Please provide implementation for this class.
```

---

> //want it to call SomeClass::SetContent(Base* value)

Note that if the template argument is deduced, it will be deduced as `Derived` not as `Base` and the argument is `Derived*`. `SomeClass::SetContent<Base>(&derived);` would already work as expected with your code (because `Derived*` can be converted to `Base*`).

Comment: lovely answer.  I have been trying to use it locally, but it does not seem to work.  I'll update soon when I can find more clarity on why it doesn't work locally.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vGcWGznjP
Here is the situation I have locally.  It doesn't work, but seems like it should?

Comment: @DannyDiaz you are missing a specialization for `T= Base` https://godbolt.org/z/77c8aqeqq. In your code you are passing a `Base*` in the question its a `Derived*`

Comment: yeah I realized after researching your post that I am trying to use pass Base* not Derived*.  I think I will mark you as correct and make another question using my more accurate (problem) code

Comment: @DannyDiaz but if you do pass `Base*` then your code in the question should be fine already

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to have all SetContent's explicit specializations to form an overload set. You will have to do it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

template <class... T>
struct Overloads : T... {
    Overloads(const T &... t) : T(t)... {}
    using T::operator()...;
};

template <class R, class... Args>
struct FunctionP {
    using F = R(Args...);
    FunctionP(F *t) : t_(t) {}
    R operator()(Args... args) const {
        return std::invoke(t_, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    F *t_;
};

struct SomeClass {
    template<typename T>
    static void SetContent(T *x) {
        Overloads o(FunctionP(&SetContentImpl<Base>)); // enumerates all the specializations here
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(o), T *>) {
            o(x);
        } else {
            SetContentImpl(x);
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void SetContentImpl(T *) {
        std::cout << "1";
    }
};

template <>
void SomeClass::SetContentImpl(Base *) {
    std::cout << "2";
}

int main() {
    SomeClass foo;
    Derived derived;
    foo.SetContent(&derived);//want it to call SomeClass::SetContent(Base* value) 
    
    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7qYbGxE3G)

Comment: Same problem here.  Why doesn't it work if the I add a 3rd class to the inheritance chain?
https://godbolt.org/z/1EcKxv3vE

Comment: @DannyDiaz The function template is specialized for `Derived` but you are trying to call it with a pointer to `Base`. It can't convert a `Base *` to `Derived *` in this context.